# Messes up class names in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm practicing Django and I've noticed something weird. For now, Im working only on the admin page. I'm defining a class model "Meetings", however, the admin panel is defined with doubles at the end, why that happens?

### models.py:

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.IntegerField(default=time(9))  # Hours
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} at {self.start_time} on {self.date}"
```

### admin.py

````
from .models import Meetings

admin.site.register(Meetings)```
````

I'm expecting it to have the same name as my definition of it, aka "Meetings"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **verbose_name_plural = 'Meetings'** of model Meta options

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.IntegerField(default=time(9))  # Hours
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} at {self.start_time} on {self.date}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Meetings'
```